# IE9 setup needs to update java/firefox/chrome?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I'm upgrading/bootstrapping a desktop with new everything Win7 64bit from Vista 32bit.

I see that IE9 is newly released and start the install.
IE9 Setup requires and offers to close these programs due to overlapping files used.

- Firefox
- Chrome
- Java(TM) Platform SE binary
- Java(TM) update scheduler
- Skype, Trillian, Winamp, etc.

How safe is this?
I fear getting yet another MS Firefox add-on or toolbar.

[image: IE9 Setup needs to update Firefox & Chrome]

Answer (score 5):

Internet Explorer is a shell wrapped around a bunch of system libraries for media handling, HTML rendering, etc.  Many other programs also use those libraries.